# sequence of promises while posting and getting data from api with angular controller and service misordered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i cant sort the following out.

- i have an angular app
- this consists of a service and a controller
- the controller interacts with the view and calls the service to

  - get entries
  - post entries
- in the background theres an api processing data...

everythings fine so far but when i post an entry and want to get all entries afterwards to update the scope, things become akward.

i think my main problem is the sequence of events/promises being wrong somehow and i can't figure out what i am doing wrong..

maybe there is someone who could help me since i spent hours on that problem now without any progress.. i read a lot and all i have read sound logical for me .. still i cant get it working..

i have created a fiddle for you guys, with a fake api in the background doing nothing... plz **have a look at the console ouput and you can see that things are happening in the wrong sequence**...

http://jsfiddle.net/ft7zjpk6/101/

### the view

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="EntryController as fake">
    <button ng-click="submit()">post entry</button>
</div>
```

### the service

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('Entry', []);

    app.factory('EntryService', function($http, $q)
    {
        var EntryService = {};

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var entries = [];

        EntryService.getEntries = function () {
            console.log('get entries');
            return entries;
        };

        EntryService.fetchEntries = function(url)
        {
            $http.get(url)
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log('fetch entries');
                    entries = data;
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error: Entries could not be fetched');
                    deferred.resolve();
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        };

        EntryService.postEntry = function(url, entry)
        {
            $http.post(url, entry)
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log('post entry');
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
                .error(function() {
                    console.log('Error: Entry could not be saved.');
                    deferred.resolve();
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return EntryService;
    });
})();
```

### the controller

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['Entry']);

    app.controller('EntryController', ['$scope', 'EntryService', function ($scope, EntryService) {
        $scope.entryService = EntryService;
        $scope.entries = {};

        loadEntries();

        function loadEntries() {
            $scope.entryService.fetchEntries('/echo/json')
                .then(function(){
                    $scope.entries = $scope.entryService.getEntries();
                });
        }

        $scope.submit = function(ngModel) {
            $scope.entryService.postEntry('/echo/json', {fakeData: 'unimportant'})
                .then(loadEntries());
        }
    }]);
})();
```

thanks for reading.. best regards
uschihund

Comment: You have to nest this promisses in order to get the expect result.

Comment: You are executing the function that you send as parameter, instead of just the method pointer -> .then(loadEntries()); use .then(loadEntries); instead.

Comment: @rvalerio you are right of course, but this doesnt solve the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Your could (should) get rid of `$q` and use the promise returned by `$http`. Moreover, code will be shorter:

```
EntryService.fetchEntries = function(url) {
    return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
               entries = response.data;
           });
}

EntryService.postEntry = function(url, entry) {
    return $http.post(url, entry);
};
```

Comment: well this solves the problem i described

edit: event though i switched to q because i suspected the sequence being wrong.. thank for responding